# NSRegularExpression change following text's color after a character

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to change a character's color and any text comes with it , I am using `NSRegularExpression` to get the character , but I have no idea how can change following characters for example here is my text :

```
● Title......
some description xxxxxx x x x x x
```

So in this case I need to change this `●`  character's color and following strings

here is the code :

```
 NSRegularExpression *regex2 = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"●"
                                   options:kNilOptions error:nil];

[regex2 enumerateMatchesInString:PureText options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:0];
    [stringText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor orangeColor] range:subStringRange];
}];

_textView.attributedText = stringText;
```

This code only finds and changes ● character's color .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex `●.*` to match all characters after the dot before the newline:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex2 = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"●.*"
                                   options:kNilOptions error:nil];

[regex2 enumerateMatchesInString:PureText options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:0];
    [stringText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor orangeColor] range:subStringRange];
}];

_textView.attributedText = stringText;
```

Comment: Try \\s\\S Instead. I fixed my answer

Comment: If you only want the first line do ●.*

Comment: Just one question , how can I change its alignment?

Comment: I'll change my answer for that

Comment: Is there any possible way to get each character between ● and next ● ? I mean for the descriptions

Comment: it change whole the text ! where can I find a guide about \\s\\S ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79164/discussion-between-mc-lover-and-sddhhanover).

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is only looking for the dot symbol. What about something like `●.*`? I'm not sure how NSRegularExpression handles newlines so you may need to represent them as well.